# No "Use nodes" option to enable while I am trying to create emission texture in blender 3.5

Tags: node-editor

I am in Cycles and have downloaded the node wrangler add-on. In the texture node editor I can't select any textures and in the modeling/layout view I have no option to use nodes. I am trying to create an emission texture using a youtube tutorial but have no option to enable the use nodes option the person in the video only mentions in passing. What to do?[image]

Comment: Hello what you show is your 3d view, you need to open a new window that you'll switch to Shader Editor

Comment: Oh my god, it was this easy all along? Thank you, I've never seen it mentioned before, everyone already starts with it open I assume.

Comment: ...or just click the Shading entry on the top menu bar and then click 'New'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is your 3d view, you need to open a new window that you'll switch to *Shader Editor*:

[image]